# Need help arrange items in a div with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to arrange a div like this but can't get it to work. [image]

What I'm getting is this[image]

My thought was to keep the image in its own column and then split the other columns into smaller rows and insert there but that doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div class="row d-flex w-100 justify-content-between products-div">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <img [src]="prod.imagePath" class="product-page-images">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <h3 class="mb-1">{{prod.name}}</h3>
                <p class="products-price-text">${{prod.price}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <h5 class="mb-1">{{prod.seller}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="mb-1">{{prod.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="main-container clearfix">
<div class="col-md-1">
  <div class="img-con">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png" alt="" />
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-11">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <small>Seller</small>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
      <h3>Price</h3>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="desc">
    description  
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

</div>
</div></div>
```

css

```
.main-container
{
  border:1px solid ;
}

.img-con
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.img-con img
{
  max-width:inherit;
  max-height:inherit;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.desc
{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

[reference link](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/JJbWom)

and style accordingly.. hope this helps